# @Immutable with @Entity and insertable=false and updateable=false on @Column

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, immutability

If I use `@Immutable` annotation on an entity and add `updatable` and `insertable` attributes on `@Column` annotation, will that be redundant?

```
@Entity
@Immutable
public class SomeEntity...
{
 @Column(name="xyz" updatable=false, insertable=false)
 private String xyz;
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the two method you can use to make your entity immutable. So yes this is redundant. I know that Hibernate (if that is what you use) will make some optimizations on entity annotated `@Immutable`. I can't tell for the `updatable=false`.